# How to use the Amazon Webservices in my iphone application?

Tags: iphone

iam developing one applciation.In that i want to use the Amazon webservices for storing the data.I dont know anything about how to use the amazon webservices in iphone application.SO please tell me how to integrate both of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to read the APIs yourself. You may use [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/)

The AWS SDK for iOS provides a library, code samples, and documentation for developers to build connected applications for iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch devices using Amazon Web Services.